# PCA gráficos en R ¿Como poner individuos en negro y circunferencia en color?

Tags: r

Me gustaría graficar los individuos de un PCA. Pero que estos aparecieran de color negro y la circunferencia que los agrupa de colores según grupos. Adjunto código y lo que obtengo hasta ahora, los individuos también se me colorean según grupos, busco evitar que eso suceda.

```
    ind.p <- fviz_pca_ind(mod, geom = "point",habillage =4, addEllipses 
    =TRUE, 
    ellipse.type = "convex")
    ggpubr::ggpar(ind.p,
          title = "Principal Component Analysis",
          subtitle = "High flight data set",
          legend.title = "Species", legend.position = "top",
          ggtheme = theme_gray()
    )
```

[image: Gráfico PCA]

Answer (score 1):

Algo como esto:

```
library("factoextra")

fviz_pca_ind( prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE), 
                      geom = "point",
                      habillage = iris$Species,
                      addEllipses = TRUE, 
                      ellipse.type = "convex",
                      col.ind = rep("black",nrow(iris))
) -> grafico

grafico
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Pero con los individuos en color negro?**

Digamos que solo es posible cuando usas  `habillage = "none"`, en cuyo caso puedes configurar el color mediante el parámetro `col.ind`. Pero si estableces una variable que contiene los grupos a colorear, pierdes la posibilidad de ajustar este valor, o al menos no he encontrado la forma natural de hacerlo.

Sin embargo hay un "hack" o truco para hacer lo que buscas. Los gráficos `ggplot` son objetos que pueden manipularse antes de ser visualizados, y están conformados por "layers" o capas, por lo que accediendo a la capa de los puntos, podemos reconfigurar el color, en este ejemplo, podríamos hacer:

```
grafico$layers[[1]]$aes_params$colour="black" # Individuos 
grafico$layers[[3]]$aes_params$colour="black" # Puuntos centrales y categorias
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para saber cuales son las capas del gráfico que corresponden a los puntos:

```
which(unlist(lapply(grafico$layers, function(x) {"GeomPoint" %in% class(x$geom)})))
```